# React Native is ignoring state change

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-state-management, react-state

Please explain why this isn't working. I am trying to replace one element with another on a button press in React, and, according to all documentation, what I am doing should work. However, React is entirely ignoring state changes and refusing to re-render an element. Here is my file:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import styles from '../styles';
import User from '../models/User';
export default class SignIn extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            signIn: '',
            errorMessage: null,
            signUp: true
        }
    }
    signIn(){
        var err = e => this.setState({errorMessage: e.message});
        var next = u => this.props.navigation.push('Details');
        User.login(this.state.email, this.state.password, err, next);
    }
    signUp(){
        var err = e => this.setState({errorMessage: e.message});
        var next = _ => this.props.navigation.push('Details');
        var user = new User(this.state.email, this.state.password);
        user.save(err, next);
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', width: 300, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={_ => this.setState({signUp: true})} style={[styles.navButton, styles.tabsButton]}>
                        <Text style={[styles.buttonText, styles.tabs]}>Sign Up</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={_ => this.setState({signUp: false})} style={[styles.grey, styles.tabsButton]}>
                        <Text style={[styles.greyText, styles.tabs]}>Sign In</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
                {this.state.signUp && <View>
                    <Text style={{color: 'red'}}>{this.state.errorMessage}</Text>
                    <TextInput 
                        placeholder={'Email'} 
                        style={styles.input} 
                        value={this.state.email} 
                        onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({email})}
                    />
                    <TextInput 
                        placeholder={'Password'} 
                        style={styles.input} 
                        secureTextEntry={true} 
                        onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({password})}
                    />
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.navButton}>
                        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Sign Up</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>      
                </View>}  
                {!this.state.signUp && <View>
                    <Text style={{color: 'red'}}>{this.state.errorMessage}</Text>
                    <TextInput 
                        placeholder={'Email'} 
                        style={styles.input} 
                        value={this.state.email} 
                        onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({email})}
                    />
                    <TextInput 
                        placeholder={'Password'} 
                        style={styles.input} 
                        secureTextEntry={true} 
                        onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({password})}
                    />
                    <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.navButton]}>
                        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Sign Up</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>       
                </View>}
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

The Sign In button at the top should change the state and cause a Sign In form to appear and the Sign Up form to disappear, while the Sign Up button should do the opposite. If I `console.log` the state after the change, it has changed, but nothing else happens. What is going on? All documentation shows that you can do this, but it doesn't work for me. I am running the app on an Android phone over Expo.

Comment: I don't quite understand your code. Can you explain why regardless the value of `this.state.signUp` you are rendering the same component?

Comment: Sorry, I figured out the issue but I can't yet close the question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
{this.state.signUp 
  ? <View>
      <Text style={{color: 'red'}}>{this.state.errorMessage}</Text>
      <TextInput 
          placeholder={'Email'} 
          style={styles.input} 
          value={this.state.email} 
          onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({email})}
      />
      <TextInput 
          placeholder={'Password'} 
          style={styles.input} 
          secureTextEntry={true} 
          onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({password})}
      />
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.navButton}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Sign Up</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>      
    </View>  
  : <View>
      <Text style={{color: 'red'}}>{this.state.errorMessage}</Text>
      <TextInput 
          placeholder={'Email'} 
          style={styles.input} 
          value={this.state.email} 
          onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({email})}
      />
      <TextInput 
          placeholder={'Password'} 
          style={styles.input} 
          secureTextEntry={true} 
          onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({password})}
      />
      <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.navButton]}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Sign Up</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>       
    </View>
}
```

If this wouldn't work, maybe styles?

Comment: @IsaacKrementsov: How can this be answer? It doesnt make sense